# How to reduce gap between two elements within a 100% width div?

Tags: css, layout, width, html

I'm working on my website header which has a logo image (100px x 100px) in the left hand corner and a navigation bar which is vertically aligned centrally using css table properties. Both the logo image and the navigation bar UL element are in a #header div which has a width of 100%.

What is the best way to reduce the gap between logo and the navigation element without ruining my layout?

[image: website 100% width header with two elements]

Added the borders so elements can be distinguished easily. I'm also using the Twitter Bootstrap framework.

The HTML for my page can be found here: http://pastebin.com/RpgcPDdh

Here is my CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom: medium none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 50px;
}

body {
    background: url("images/maze_bg.png") repeat scroll 0 0 #DDDDDD 
}

#header {
    display: table;
    padding: 20px 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#header ul{
    border: solid 1px red;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#header img{
    border: solid 1px blue;
}
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: do you want to move one or both of them? Or make one bigger? The whitespace has to be traded with something...

Comment: I want to move the navigation closer to the logo.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/RpgcPDdh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

padding-right did the trick! I guess I should've persevered instead of creating a question on here.

Answer (score 1):

Throw in a

`margin-right: 20px;`

or something on the `#header ul`. That will move it left.

Comment: I attempted this in Firebug a little while ago but it didn't make a difference. I just tried it again, this time editing my CSS file but still no difference. I'm on FF 18.0.2.

Comment: @Sid Ugh, its probably because you are displaying that stuff as a table-cell. Did you try setting the width of the image tag to how wide it actually is?

Comment: Nope, but I just tried padding-right on the #header ul and that worked!